# facebox white gap

Tags: css, facebox

I want to load facebox programatically, and it should display the contents of a div as below:

```
$.facebox({ div: '#inline_demo' });
```

the problem is that the div which is hidden, has a 600x600 image in it that will be displayed on the facebox. So the browser shows a big gap, and the scrollers move up as if there was content there. Overflow is set to hidden for that div, but still.

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `display:none`?

Then change it to `display:block` upon activation...